# J48 not working in weka explorer

Tags: java, linux, data-mining, weka

I am not able to use GUI of weka in linux (linux mint 9). 
It doesn't allows me to use J48 from [interface](http://imageshare.web.id/images/fpux7tvf4y1oeesmw2.png), whereas I am able to run it from command prompt.

Can anyone tell me what is can be the problem with it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

J48 is expecting nominal class and therefore it is filtered out if your class is numeric.

If this is the case you should run a NumericToNominal Filter in the Preprocess stage. Note to state the index of the class column for the filter to run only on it.